# How to correctly make Create DM request in Discord API?

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

I am trying to create dm

```
import requests
import json

url = 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/@me/channels'
token = 'token'
body = {
    'recipient_id': '123456789'
}

data = {'data':json.dumps(body)}
headers = {
    "Authorization": token,
    "Content-Type":"application/json"
}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
print(r.content)
print(r.text)
```

This code receives response with "400: Bad request" message.
I've read [this](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#create-dm) but I can't find any examples of correct usage of this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood my mistake, I shouldn't pass dictionary as data but should pass a str, so I changed `data=data` to `data=json.dumps(data)` and it worked